# calculate covariance matrix formula

Tags: covariance, labview

I am trying to calculate 3d covariance matrix and I use this formula:

[image: covariance matrix 3D]

But I got a different result when I use covariance matrix.vi in LabVIEW. 
This is the link to the .vi file and matrix data which include 3 columns for `x1`; `x2`; `x3`
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/du0oj32bwvn583s/AADZ7fxoNIIkHAZKSQpDUYe2a?dl=0

Could you please tell me what did I do wrong and why there is a difference?

Answer (score 0):

So the formula I used is not correct. Below is the correct formula for mean and covariance matrix.

[image: Correct formula]